# By using stored procedure, if a price is updated in one branch then it should be automatically reflected in all the branches

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

These are the tables I have created and inserted the values:

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(Branch_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
 Branch_Name VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Branch  (Branch_Name)
VALUES('Inala')
INSERT INTO Branch  (Branch_Name)
VALUES('Richlands')
INSERT INTO Branch  (Branch_Name)
VALUES('Forest Lake')


CREATE TABLE Product
(Product_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Product_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Product_Price INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Branch_No INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(Product_No)
 )


INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Pepsi',2,1)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('7UP',2,1)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Mirinda',2,1)
INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Pepsi',2,2)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('7UP',2,2)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Mirinda',2,2)
INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Pepsi',2,3)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('7UP',2,3)
INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name,Product_Price,Branch_No)
VALUES('Mirinda',2,3)
```

Now what I want to achieve is that if I update a product price in one branch, then that particular updated product price should be automatically reflected on all branches. 
For example, Pepsi Price in Inala branch is 2 dollars, If I update the Pepsi price to 3 dollars in Inala branch then that updated Pepsi price should be automatically reflected on all the other branches (Richlands and Forest Lake). In other words, I don't have to separately update Pepsi Price again for Richlands and Forest Lake branch.

This is what I have tried in my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProductPrice
@ProductNo INTEGER,
@ProductPrice INTEGER,
@BranchName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Product
SET Product_Price = @ProductPrice
WHERE Product_No = @ProductNo
AND @BranchName = (SELECT Branch_Name FROM Branch)
END
```

Stored Procedure was successfully created.
Then I used EXECUTE command.

```
EXECUTE UpdateProductPrice 1,1,'Inala'
```

I got the following error message:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

It would be helpful, if an appropriate Stored Procedure Syntax solution is provided.

Comment: Start over - put some real constraints into your table before you discover the many ways to corrupt your data. A synthetic primary key is not sufficient to guarantee that each row represents a single "thing". You should have unique constraints on the natural keys as well. Pricing is generally specific to a date or a period - often to a place. It is unusual to have a 1:1 relationship between product, branch, and price. And lastly, you would not have this problem if your product table was properly normalized.

Comment: And you have a DDL error - Product.BranchNo is not a foreign key to Product.ProductNo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a INNER JOIN on `Product` & `Branch`. And the conditions you want are all specified in `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE p
SET    Product_Price = @ProductPrice
FROM   Product p
       INNER JOIN Branch b ON p.Branch_No = b.Branch_No 
WHERE  Product_No   = @ProductNo
AND   b.Branch_Name = @BranchName
```

Note : this only resolved the error in your stored procedure.

On your other requirement, you mean once a price for a product is change, all branches should also reflect the change ? If this is the case, then you don't need to pass in the `@BranchName` at all. You can simply update based on `@ProductNo`

```
UPDATE p
SET    Product_Price = @ProductPrice
FROM   Product p
WHERE  Product_No   = @ProductNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your stored procedure parameters can't change, try this out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProductPrice
@ProductNo INTEGER,
@ProductPrice INTEGER,
@BranchName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ProductName VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Product_Name FROM Product WHERE Product_No 
= @ProductNo)
UPDATE Product
SET Product_Price = @ProductPrice
WHERE Product_Name = @ProductName
END
```

Grab the product name of the record you're passing in the parameters, then update the price for all records with the same name.

If your parameters CAN change, consider designing the procedure around the name.

Here's another option:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Product_Price = @ProductPrice
FROM Product a
    JOIN Product b
        ON a.Product_Name = b.Product_Name
        AND b.Product_No = @ProductNo
    JOIN Branch c
        ON b.Branch_No = c.Branch_No
        AND c.Branch_Name = @BranchName
```

Use joins to restrict the records you're updating in the table. Same concept without creating additional variables.

Comment: Just a while ago ... I solved it before you posted your answer ... Instead of putting ProductNo as input parameter ... I have put ProductName as input parameter and I have also removed BranchName input parameter and it worked ... I have also posted an answer ... You may have a look

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem 
This is what I did and it worked:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProductPrice
@ProductName VARCHAR(20),
@ProductPrice INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Product
SET Product_Price = @ProductPrice
WHERE Product_Name = @ProductName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you model lacks normalization. This is not okay to copy product description per each branch and then *update them all*. Your model is missing M:M table like that:

```
       1       M                M         1
Product---------BranchAssortment-----------Branch
```

If `same price for all branches` is a business rule of yours, then you don't need `PriceList` tables for now and it's fine to keep `price` inside `product`.

Such a model will avoid product copies and all the issues with keeping them synchronized.

And your attempt to update specific product with `WHERE Product_No = @ProductNo` will finally succeed.